# Find or estimate constant in inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For given $0<\alpha<1$ I want to find a constant $C(\alpha)>0$ (minimal as possible) such that for any positive numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n >0$ the equality holds
$$
    (x_1^\alpha+\ldots+x_n^\alpha)^{\frac 1 \alpha} \leqslant C(\alpha) (x_1^2 + \ldots+x_n^2)^{\frac 1 2}.
$$
If  $\alpha \geqslant 1$ it can be done with help of Hölder inequality, but for $\alpha<1$ I have no idea what to use. I tried with derivative of left hand side with respect to $\alpha$ but the resulting expression seems intractable.

Comment: If you want to do this directly without using any known estimates, you can use the Lagrange multiplier method. Indeed, by compactness of the Euclidean sphere and homogeneity of your inequality, there exists an optimal $C(\alpha)$ and it is attained. You can compute $C(\alpha)^\alpha$ by maximization of $f(x)=\sum x_j^\alpha$ on the Euclidean sphere. For the extrema, the gradients of $f$ and $g(x)=\sum x_j^2$ are proportional. This forces the nonzero $x_j$'s to be equal. Now compare the $n$ values of $f$ this gives.

Comment: The largest one is $C(\alpha)^\alpha=n^{1-\alpha/2}$. So $C(\alpha)=n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{2}}=n^\frac{2-\alpha}{2\alpha}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could prove that by means of the generalized mean inequality, which is itself proven by Jensen's inequality.
So, the statement is: if you define the $\alpha$th mean of $x:=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to be
$$
M(\alpha, x):=\left(\frac{x_1^\alpha+\ldots, x_n^\alpha}{n}\right)^{1/\alpha}
$$
you always have that, whenever $\alpha \leq \beta$, $M_\alpha(x) \leq M_\beta(x)$.
See [here](http://planetmath.org/proofofgeneralmeansinequality) for a proof. You have equality when all the $x_i$'s are equal, and from that you can deduce optimality of the constant you find.

Comment: I see, but... For $p\geqslant q>0$ we have that $\|x\|_p \leqslant \|x\|_q$ and since your $M(\alpha,x) = \|x\|_\alpha$ it gives is the converse inequality for $\|x\|_p$ and $\|x\|_q$. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing the wrong thing. Now it should work...

Comment: Good, now it works nice. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!